# Check two table against each other and if Table A exists in Table B update A

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2016

Before I ask anything I would like to be clear that I am requesting help with coursework. Unfortunately what I am trying to do has not been covered within the course.

I have been asked to build a MS Access database to manage and maintain a Console Games Library.

I have two tables, tblGames and tblLoans.

I am trying to make it so that if the game_ID in tblGames exists within tblLoans it updates tblGames to show that the game is currently unavailable. I am to do this with a query.

Within tblGames I have a foreign key "game_ID" (autonumber) which links to tblLoans column "game".

The issue is that I have 0 idea how to do this. I ahve tried looking up information on how to do this, unfortunately any information I can find is someone giving a tailored answer to an issue or is not relevant to my needs. I am sure this is in part to my not using the correct terms when searching for information as I am not entirely sure of the correct terms.

I am not necessarily looking for the answer but rather some direction to help me find the answer myself (though an example solution with an explanation of what it does would be very helpful)

Thank you for your time.

NB: We will actually be covering queries in class the week after this assignment is due. Overall the course itself has been horribly designed and the lecturer is uncooperative and unhelpful. We are currently taking this issue up with the head of department as it is obviously not acceptable.

Answer (score 0):

This is one possible way:

1. Create a new query
2. Apply this example query to your table structure:

.

```
UPDATE tblGames AS g
SET g.game_ID = (
  SELECT game
  FROM tblLoans
  WHERE game = yourParameter
);
```

This part checks if a game with "yourParameter" exists within tblLoans.

```
SELECT game
FROM tblLoans
WHERE game = yourParameter
```

If it finds anything game_ID in tbl Games gets updated.

It really is didactically unsound that you get an assignment about queries before you cover queries in class.

Comment: I tried doing that, unfortunately it doesn't seem to work, though I geel that may be because I have not fully explained what I am trying to do.

I have two tables:
tblGames with columns game_ID (autonumber) and available (yes/no)
tblLoans with column game (number)

tblGames.game_ID and tblLoans.game are connected so that when I create a new loan it will connect to a game from the tblGames.

What I need to do is if within tblLoans.game exists an entry from tblGames.game_ID then update tblGames.available to be false.

It is a rather odd lesson plan, thank you for your help though.